# Can I Set Nested Values on MOXy DynamicEntities that are null?

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am using the EclipseLink MOXy Dynamic Entity Creation and having trouble with one thing.  My app hold no libraries in the codebase for downstream SOAP services.  But on startup creates all of the objects using *DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD()*.  From here, I take my own locally defined objects and convert them using metadata in the app.  If my downstream objects are simple, with no nested classes, I can create the converted objects with no problem.  But say I have a downstream DynamicType like:

```
class Person {
    class Address {
        String city;
        String state;
    }
    String first;
    String last;
    Address address;
}
```

I've tried to create the person object using the set by XPath methods:

```
DynamicEntity person = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity(jaxbContext.getDynamicType( "Person" ));
jaxbContext.setValueByXPath( person, "first/text()", null, "Tres");
jaxbContext.setValueByXPath( person, "last/text()", null, "Bailey");
jaxbContext.setValueByXPath( person, "address/city/text()", null, "Cowpens");
jaxbContext.setValueByXPath( person, "address/state/text()", null, "SC");
```

The first 2 set values work, but if person is a brand new object, the latter 2 lines that set the city and state do not set the values.  It makes sense that they would not work, since the address object is not already set with a value.  But in my use case, I am trying to avoid having service-specific bindings files and would like to not have to iterate through each of my DynamicTypes to find the fields and its type on each setting.  Is this even possible in MOXy?

I use EclipseLink version 2.5 and running on Tomcat 7 with Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You would need to do something like the following:

```
    jaxbContext.setValueByXPath( person, "first/text()", null, "Tres");
    jaxbContext.setValueByXPath( person, "last/text()", null, "Bailey");

    Object address = jaxbContext.createByXPath(person, "address", null, Object.class);
    jaxbContext.setValueByXPath(person, "address", null, address);

    jaxbContext.setValueByXPath( person, "address/city/text()", null, "Cowpens");
    jaxbContext.setValueByXPath( person, "address/state/text()", null, "SC");
```

I can see the behaviour you are looking for in your question.  Would you mind entering an enhancement request using the link below:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

Comment: Thank you.  I've created an enhancement request, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415191  The example you show here is more efficient using the createByXPath method than the work-around I had created, so this is very a useful alternative.